# TableSpacing oddity

Tags: bugs, front-end, output-formatting, grid-layouts

**Bug introduced in 8.0 or earlier and persisting through 12.0**

---

```
TableForm[Partition[Range@9, 3], TableSpacing -> {0, 0.5}]
```

[image: tighter]

```
TableForm[Partition[Range@9, 3], TableSpacing -> {0, 1/2}]
```

[image: looser]

Note that the second result has looser spacing than the first. These are images taken of those notebook cells. (This is more evident with larger arrays, but these are big enough to see the effect.)

So why is `0.5` not the same as `1/2`?

I am running *Mathematica* 11.1.0.0 on MacOS Sierra 10.12.3.

Comment: `TableForm[Partition[Range@12, 4], TableSpacing -> {0, 0.5}] === 
 TableForm[Partition[Range@12, 4], TableSpacing -> {0, 1/2}]` returns `False` in my case too.

Comment: That they're not equal is expected, since the forms you are comparing have the 0.5 and 1/2 in them. (You can use `FullForm` to look at what you're comparing.) What is odd is that the displayed tables look different.

Comment: I see the same problem in MMA 11.1.0 on WIndows.

Comment: The same problem is seen in `GridBox` with `ColumnSpacings` and `RowSpacings` attributes. Interestingly, `Grid` seems to have no problem with `Spacings`.

Comment: @Mark Adler are not the structures of the two tableforms compared? I will check using FullForm.

Comment: Did you report this to Wolfram?

Comment: No, I haven't. I'm not sure I even want to report it, since there are probably other bugs that would be more worthy of their time to deal with.

Answer (score 12):

I see the same with versions 8.0.4, 10.4.1 and 11.1.0 on Windows 7 x64. Only with version 5.2 the outputs are formatted identically.

Let us look at the underlying box expression printed in the Notebook in each case (the following is the output from version 11.1.0):

```
CellPrint[ExpressionCell[TableForm[Partition[Range@4, 2], TableSpacing -> {0, #}], 
     "Output", CellTags -> "GridSpacings"]] & /@ {.5, 1/2};
cells = NotebookRead /@ Cells[CellTags -> "GridSpacings"];
Cases[#, Verbatim[Rule][GridBoxSpacings, _], -2] & /@ cells
```

> [image: screenshot]
>
> ```
> {{GridBoxSpacings -> {"Columns" -> {Offset[0.28], {Offset[0.35]}, Offset[0.28]}, 
>     "ColumnsIndexed" -> {}, "Rows" -> {Offset[0.2], {Offset[0.]}, Offset[0.2]}, 
>     "RowsIndexed" -> {}}}, 
>  {GridBoxSpacings -> {"Columns" -> {Offset[0.28], {1/2}, Offset[0.28]}, 
>     "ColumnsIndexed" -> {}, "Rows" -> {Offset[0.2], {Offset[0.]}, Offset[0.2]}, 
>     "RowsIndexed" -> {}}}}
> ```

One can see essential difference in the spacing specifications for `"Columns"`! These `GridBox` options are all undocumented, but if we assume that their forms are the same as for [`Spacings`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Spacings.html) we are confused again because in our case the middle term shouldn't matter:

> `{s1,{c},sn}`     use *`s1`*, then repeatedly use *`c`*, but use *`sn`* at the end

Oh, `Gid` has a lot of "oddities", probably this is just another one.

But what makes things even more painful is that the above *oddity* is due to a [conversion performed solely by the FrontEnd](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6260185/590388), because the Kernel's `ToBoxes` creates numerically identical expressions:

```
N@ToBoxes@TableForm[Partition[Range@4, 2], TableSpacing -> {0, .5}] ===
 N@ToBoxes@TableForm[Partition[Range@4, 2], TableSpacing -> {0, 1/2}]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

Hence we can't catch such an "oddity" without conversation with the FrontEnd.